# header location и прокси

Tags: php

Добрый день! Есть сайт `suite.ru`, к нему можно получить доступ через прокси `suite.p2.p1.ru`, проблема в том, что на сайте стоит пере адресация на  `http://$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, а это ломает прокси, но если убрать `http://`, то перенаправляет на `suite.p2.p1.ru/suite.p2.p1.ru`, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: чот не очень уверен, что проблема в пхп... и не совсем понятно что надо в итоге... и что такое "ломает прокси" -- демон надо перезапускать? :)

Comment: Нужно чтобы при переадресации suite.p2.p1.ru на suite.p2.p1.ru/home.php, а не на suite.p2.p1.ru/suite.p2.p1.ru/home.php

Comment: а на каком сайте стоит переадресация? что за прокси используется? вообще обработку такх велосипедов лучше устраивать на прокси серверах жеж.